# SUMIF Column A if Column B is greater than or equal to Column C in another dataframe

Tags: r, sum, iteration, conditional-statements

I would like to sum the values in columns in df1 if the corresponding values in the first column [A] in df1 are greater than or equal to a value in df2. I have a range of values I would like to do this for in df2.

In excel the formula would look something like:
SUMIF(df1$A,>=df2$Value,df1$B) for one column.

df1:

```
  [A]    [B]    [C]
    1     10     20
    2     20     20
    3     20     30
    4     10     50
    5     30     10
```

df2:

```
Value
    1
    3
    5
```

OUTPUT:

```
Value   SUM[df1$B]   SUM[df1$C]
    1           90          130
    3           60           90
    5           30           10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try with `base R`.  Loop over the 'Value' column of 'df2', subset the 'df1' based on the condition whether the 'A' column is greater than or equal to the value in 'df2', get the column sums of 'B' and 'C' columns, `rbind` the `list` elements to create a single dataset

```
res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(df2$Value, function(x) cbind(Value = x, 
            as.data.frame.list(colSums(df1[df1$A >= x, 2:3])))))
names(res)[-1] <- paste0("SUM_", names(res)[-1])
res
#     Value SUM_B SUM_C
#1     1    90   130
#2     3    60    90
#3     5    30    10
```

---

Or another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
CJ(A=df1$A, Value = df2$Value)[A >= Value][df1, on = .(A)
             ][, lapply(.SD, sum),Value, .SDcols = B:C]
#   Value  B   C
#1:     1 90 130
#2:     3 60  90
#3:     5 30  10
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea via base R,

```
cbind(df2,  
      setNames(data.frame(t(sapply(df2$value, function(i) 
                                       sapply(2:ncol(df1), function(j) 
                                                 sum(df[i:nrow(df1), j]))))), 
               paste0('SUM', '_', names(df1)[-1])))
```

which gives,

> ```
>    value SUM_V2 SUM_V3
> 1     1     90    130
> 2     3     60     90
> 3     5     30     10
> ```